# .Net Core 2.1 new Angular version

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Is there a way to select the Angular version when using the standard command line interface where you set up a new Angular project.  I'd like to be able to designate either version 5 or 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,it is not possible because that is a template which is build on x day then y day may be they were not update this cli package.So when you install package on z day you got x days package. In short angular team updated this cli package but integration (which is not build by angular team) with angular and asp.net core package not updated.

So you can delete everything from clientApp directory and then install angular's quick start project from the cli.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks baj9032